# Django: filter ManyToMany join

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have app where subscribers are subscribing to various lists.
The domain here is: List model/SubscriberModel/ListSubscription model.

The List class definition contains the following line

```
subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(Subscriber, through='ListSubscription')
```

While this code allows me to get all subscribers, I need only some of them. the trick is that ListSubscription
class contains "is_active" boolean field identifiying subscriptions that are either active or inactive.
Is there some straighforward solution to add "is_active=True" to many to many join?
In plain SQL I would add this condition to a join clause, but not sure about Django ORM way.

The ideal result here would be ability to have a queryset to get all Lists with respective *active" subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

A `ManyToMany` field is already a queryset, so if you want the active subscribers you can just call its `filter` method, perhaps via a method in the `List` class. The `through` table is available for filtering in the same way as the target table:

```
class List(models.Model):
    # ... etc ...
    @property
    def active_subscribers(self):
        return self.subscribers.filter(listsubscription__is_active = True)
```

To return lists with at least one active subscriber, use this query:

```
List.objects.filter(listsubscription__is_active = True)
```